# No resource identifier found

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create an app with a collapsible toolbar but getting an error "No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_collapseMode' in package android"

i have tried adding different libraries in gradle but error still persists

[this is the errors and the highlighted xml code for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkBvm.png)

Comment: Please don't put pictures of code and warnings.  Copy the text instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change the prefix to ***app***:layout_collapseMode="parallax"  from ***android***:layout_collapseMode="parallax" on line 36.

Also, this line should belong in the RelativeLayout(parent of the ImageView), which is a direct child of the CollapsingToolbarLayout if you intend to achieve parallax collapsing of the layout.